# Undetectable memory leak in vuejs application

Tags: json, memory-management, memory-leaks, vue.js

I've been trying to resolve this problem for a while now, I even gave it a shot to rewrite the entire program but without success. The application is running on VueJS 2.3.3 and is supposed to be running on Chromium in combination with a Raspberry Pi (irrelevant information, for now).

We're working with several components which are being included in a single file, later on this file will be compiled using either `gulp` or `npm run dev`. When the instance of `VueJS` initializes, a request will be send using `Vue Resource`'s `$http` option. This'll receive a json response with a size of around `30mb`. This'll be saved in the data array, as seen here:

```
this.$http.get('<url>' + this.token)
    .then((response) => {
        this.properties = response.properties;
    });
```

This data will later on be used for further actions, another thing that is worth mentioning is that the data is being refreshed every once in a while. Which is where I think the problem occurs, if I'm not refreshing the data every 5 minutes (can be longer too, really depends on the way I'm testing) the program runs fine. It's just that I want to refresh the data every once in a while to retrieve new information. The way of setting a timeout which I'm using is as following:

```
this.dataTimeout = setTimeout(this.refreshData, 300000);
```

Each (so called) `property` has at least 6 base64 images saved in it's JSON, which are later used to present to the user. Besides that, there is a name, address, and some other tiny bits of data. It doesn't sound all that wrong but I'm getting the feeling that each response makes the memory grow so intense that even a desktop is getting trouble running it.

Each 10 seconds a new `property` will be presented on the user's screen including the images, street, location, etc. I'm not sure if there is a memory leak in my code or if I'm forgetting something. A few questions pop up in my head:

1. Do I need to reset the response I'm getting from the server back to
   `null` or `undefined`?
2. Could there be a leak in one of the plugins I'm using (Just VueResources)?
3. For how long can a `VueJS` instance stay alive, is there any recommended time to reload the entire program?
4. What thinks should I take in consideration in order to achieve this at all?

I've taken out the data renewal and put a demo project online, this can be seen right [here](http://mtvslide.sqitsup.nl/65688e0b-7986-44d7-b810-c0333c9b9747). The main problem I'm having is that the browser just runs out of memory and shows us the amazing `Aw snap!` page from Chrome. I tried taking snapshots from the memory usage but it all seems fine, it just explodes randomly after a while.

Comment: I am somehow at the exact same problem. I am running a vue application in chromium browser on raspberry pi 3 / 4 and it seems like chromium-browser (but also electron) can't let go of unused memory, even fills up the memory in matter of hours (depends on content) and resulting in "aw snap!" . I wasn't able to see any memory leaks in the application itself. The only thing helping to free the memory is to close and restart chromium.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know what really does your app, but are your 30Mb of data really useful / essential ? In JSON moreover ?

Maybe you don't need all this data, and you could just adapt the data to your needs. For example, keep your JSON store data, and retrieve your Base64 images by another way.

I don't understand why you store in memory images. Images are just useful for display purpose in my opinion.

So I think 30Mb is really huge. But maybe I'm wrong ?

By the way, I've tested with Firefox Nightly, no problem here. Doesn't seem to crash. Maybe I don't encounter the refresh call ?

Comment: The refresh has been turned off at the online version to demonstrate the thing we're doing. We're keeping the images as a base64 in the json so that whenever the computer doesn't have internet, the images can still be displayed. and the 30mb is still quite small, some steps in the application has around 720 images. Sums up to a few hundred mbs.. we've tried storing those in a local storage but we couldn't allocate the right size on the Pi. I'll turn the data refreshing on and upload it, I'll give a heads up when it's online. :)

Comment: I've turned it on, it's not switching slides this time. It's refreshing data 10 seconds after it's done downloading. the size currently is around 38.5mb, I also ran gulp in production mode.

Comment: Well, in fact each refresh raise the memory consumption. I'm currently at 420 MB. Too much for a webapp like this.

I think you have to try to not store images inside VueJS reactivity system.

Comment: Where would we have to store them, any idea? I have tried the local storage, didn't work out. Even tried the local sql storage, but that ended up being way too much load too.

Comment: Well, as I'm not sure what you try to do with all these files, what I can just say is that's not a good idea to integrate binary data into Vue reactivity system...
If you wanna 'prefetch' images before using it, I think you can do differently. For example by inserting the `<img>` element with a `display:none` css rule ?
If you wanna store these files to go offline, don't know exactly how you could do that, because I don't know if your files are depending on the user ? Maybe go to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers